# CMake conformance mode for MSVC

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cmake, standards-compliance

I develop in Linux and I am trying to test the project with MSVC.

Currently, I realize that MSVC is trying to compile the C++ project using the MSVC dialect of C++, and apparently, I have to force MSVC to compile in "conformance mode", I believe that I need to pass options like `/std:c++17 /EHsc /permissive- /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline` to the compiler.

I guess I can configure MSVC to pass these options, but a more elegant solution would be to set these options directly in the CMake, so I state these options for once.

What is the typical idiom to do this?

I for example used these, thinking that it will translate into MSVC into compiling with the conformant options, but it is not the case.

```
if (NOT DEFINED CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
endif()
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)
```

(or the more modern `target_compile_features(my_target INTERFACE cxx_std_17>)`)

I am using Version 17.6.5.

Comment: in CMake   "CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS=OFF" doesn't mean "/permissive-" https://discourse.cmake.org/t/cxx-extensions-and-permissive/1994 and https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/17068

Comment: This looks like the "old" way of setting the C++ standard version. I don't recall the exact name, it starts with target_, though.

Comment: @sweenish, sure, it was a example. It is `target_compile_features(my_target INTERFACE cxx_std_17>)`

Comment: I guess that's just a typo, but it should be `target_compile_features(my_target INTERFACE cxx_std_17)`; Furthermore to apply the settings to the `my_target` target, you need to use `PUBLIC` or `PRIVATE` instead of `INTERFACE`, otherwise only targets linking `my_target` are affected by the setting. Furthermore you may want to go with `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17 CACHE STRING "")` to define a default value that can be overwritten by the user during configuration...

Answer (score 2):

Ok, there might be no idiomatic way to do this.

```
target_compile_options(
  my_target PUBLIC
  $<$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>: /permissive- /volatile:iso
  # /EHsc /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline  # might be necesssary for more compliance
  # /WX /W4 # if you want to add optimizations here
  >
)
```

Editorial note: <s>it is silly that MS calls "permissive" to standard compliance.
It is the opposite meaning.
They had been permissive in the way they allowed highly non-standard codes.</s>

It is "permissive-minus"! :)

Comment: It's `/permissive` to be permissive. Conformance mode is `/permissive-`. MSVC convention is to turn off flags with a `-`. So, while it may seem silly to the uninitiated, it's just being consistent.

Comment: Ah, that explains the `-` !... LOL

Comment: Note, you shold rather use `target_compile_options`, not `target_compile_definitions`, the latter modifies its input with `-D`, `/D` etc. and is intended for preprocessor symbols visible in compilation.

Comment: @R2RT, fixed, I must have copy-pasted the wrong command. I didn't test it.

Answer (score 0):

my way:

```
if (MSVC)
   set(CXX_STANDARD "/std:c++latest")
   set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${CXX_STANDARD} /std:c++17 /EHsc /permissive- /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline")
else()
    ...
endif()
```

Comment: Probably should remove `/std:c++17` and keep only `/std:c++latest`, or the other way around.